# fff.h testing framework: ‘call_count’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, unit-testing

I've just started using the [Fake Function Framework (fff)](https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff) for testing low-level C code and it's delightful.  But I'm stuck on one thing: I'm getting a compile-time error:

```
test/test_mu_task.c: In function ‘test_task_setting_state’:
test/test_mu_task.c:57:51: error: request for member ‘call_count’ in something not a structure or union
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT(test_task_set_state_hook.call_count, 0);
```

Here are the excerpts from my test file:

```
#include "fff.h"
#include "../src/mu_task.h"

FAKE_VOID_FUNC(test_task_set_state_hook, mu_task_t *, mu_task_state_t);
static mu_task_t s_test_task;
void test_task_setting_state(void) {
    ...
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT(test_task_set_state_hook.call_count, 0); // <= error is here...
    ...
}
```

My understanding was the `FAKE_VOID_FUNC` would create a fake function, all equipped with `.call_count` and `arg0_val` slots, etc.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the section "Hello Fake World" on the home page at the GitHub repo you link to indicates that for `FAKE_VOID_FUNC(somename)`, the data structure is `somename_fake`. Your example is missing the `_fake`. (The example uses the names `DISPLAY_init` and `DISPLAY_init_fake`. In your code, `test_task_set_state_hook` is a (pointer to a) function — those don't have members (hence the error message).

```
#include "fff.h"
#include "../src/mu_task.h"

FAKE_VOID_FUNC(test_task_set_state_hook, mu_task_t *, mu_task_state_t);
static mu_task_t s_test_task;
void test_task_setting_state(void) {
    …
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT(test_task_set_state_hook_fake.call_count, 0); // <= fix is here.
    …
}
```

Comment: Doh!  Totally missed that (and the name mangling makes sense).  Thank you!